# Configure result backend for Celery chord tasks only?

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

Is it possible to configure the result backend for the chord tasks only? Or do I need to configure a generic result backend for all the tasks in the Celery app to use chords?

I already have the result backend configured for certain tasks, but I would like to avoid configuring it for all tasks. How can I use chords in this case?